# LINQ in ItemBinding to add columns to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` bound to an `ObservableCollection<MachineOrder>` where I want to add some columns programmatically.

The object `MachineOrder` contains another `ObservableCollection<KeyValue>` from which I want to add the columns.

The thing is that I want to display a specific Key in the `ObservableCollection` for each row. The index isn't always the same so I cant use that.

I tried it this way:

```
foreach (StringWrapper characteristic in viewModel.Characteristics)
{
     Binding binding = new Binding();
     binding.FallbackValue = "kein Wert";
     binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Charakteristics.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == characteristic.Value).Value");

     DataGridTextColumn columnActive = new DataGridTextColumn();
     columnActive.Header = characteristic.Value;
     columnActive.Width = new DataGridLength(0, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
     columnActive.Binding = binding;
}
```

But the linq expression does not work here. Btw: `viewModel.Characteristics` contains a list of characteristics which I want to add to the `DataGrid`

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all: you should use "Characteristics", not "Charakteristics" (c not k). Although it won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, you can only bind to properties. So to solve the problem, just make a property and bind to it.

First, instead on `ObservableCollection<KeyValue>` create a custom derived collection to be used inside your `MachineOrder` class.

```
public class KeyValueCollection : ObservableCollection<KeyValue>
{
    public Value this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            var item = this.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);
            return item != null ? item.Value : null;
        } 
    }
}
```

The whole purpose is to define a new indexer property by key. Note that I don't have your `KeyValue` class, so the return type would be different.

Then you can bind to that property like this

```
foreach (StringWrapper characteristic in viewModel.Characteristics)
{
    // ...
    binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Characteristics[\"" + characteristic.Value + "\"]");
    //...
}
```